# Is Spider-Man the only Marvel character that has been represented as multiple non-human characters?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Spider-Man has been represented as multiple non-human creatures:

- Pter Ptarker - A Pteranodon in a Tyrannosaurus rex body.
- Peter Porker (Spider-Ham) - A Spider, that was bitten by an irradiated Anthropomorphic pig.

Has any other Marvel character in any continuity been represented as a non-human character/creature that is not the same as their first representation?

Comment: 'gator Loki :-D

Comment: Un-dead Stephen Strange. non-human*oid*

Comment: I guess [spider pig](https://youtu.be/t5AXmXDfm00) is canon now?

Comment: if you enlarge the question to include DC: https://superman.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lady_and_the_Lion https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPHsW.png

Comment: I know you're asking about Marvel, but in the Eddas Loki is Sleipnir's mother. So they have to get quite weird to get weirder than the stories they're based on.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Deadpool** has been portrayed as several non-human characters.

Among them is a dog — **Dogpool** from *[Prelude to Deadpool Corps](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Prelude_to_Deadpool_Corps_Vol_1_3)* (2010).

[image: Dogpool]

[image: Dogpool] [image: Dogpool]

In *[Deadpool the Duck](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool_the_Duck_Vol_1_1)* (2017), Deadpool fused with Howard the Duck and became [**Deadpool the Duck**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool_the_Duck_(Earth-616)).

[image: Deadpool the Duck] [image: Deadpool the Duck]

Deadpool was also portrayed as a dinosaur — **Deadpool Dinosaur** (amalgam with [Devil Dinosaur](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_Dinosaur_(Earth-78411))) in [*Deadpool Kills Deadpool* Vol. 1 #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool_Kills_Deadpool_Vol_1_3).

[image]

Some of the other non-human Deadpool variants ([full list here](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Character_Index/Earth-Unknown-D#Deadpool)):

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

---

**Kang the Conqueror** has been represented as multiple non-human creatures (members of the "Council of Kangs") in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023 MCU film).

[image: Council of Kangs]

The above scene took inspiration from the "[Council of Cross-Time Kangs](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Council_of_Cross-Time_Kangs_(Multiverse))" in *[Avengers #292](https://www.marvel.com/articles/comics/who-are-the-council-of-kangs-in-the-comics)* (1988).

[image]

---

**Doctor Strange** met a variant of himself, **Doctor Stranger Yet**, who was a warthog, in [*Doctor Strange* Vol. 2 #25](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_2_25) (1977).

[image: Doctor Stranger Yet]

<sup>(Thanks to [Bjorn Eriksson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/105008/bjorn-eriksson), for mentioning this in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276035/is-spider-man-the-only-marvel-character-that-has-been-represented-as-multiple-no/276045?noredirect=1#comment761294_276045). Image is from: https://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/doctor_strange_2428.shtml)</sup>

---

**Captain America** (Steve Rogers) has been portrayed as a werewolf — **CapWolf** in [*Captain America*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_405) Vol. 1 #405 (1992).

[image: CapWolf]

**Sam Wilson** as **Captain America** has also been portrayed as **CapWolf** in *[Captain America: Sam Wilson](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America:_Sam_Wilson_Vol_1_3)* Vol. 1 #3 (2015).

[image: CapWolf]

---

A variant of **Loki**, “[**Alligator Loki**](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Alligator_Loki)”, made its appearance in Season 1 of *Loki* (2021 MCU TV show).

[image: Alligator Loki]

---

**Loki** has been depicted as a cat in an alternate cover by Skottie Young for [*Thor: God of Thunder* Vol. 1 #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor:_God_of_Thunder_Vol_1_1) (2012).

[image: Loki as a cat]

<sup>(Thanks to [Trish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102189/trish) for mentioning this in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276035/is-spider-man-the-only-marvel-character-that-has-been-represented-as-multiple-no/276045?noredirect=1#comment762041_276045).)</sup>

---

**[Dino-Thor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dino-Thor_(Earth-23134))**, a variant of **Thor** who is a humanoid dinosaur and a member of the [Thor Corps](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Corps_(Earth-15513)), appeared in *Spider-Island* #5 (2015) and *Secret Wars* #7 (2015).

[image]

---

A variant of **Thor** who is a humanoid boar and member of the [Thor Corps](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Corps_(Earth-15513)) appeared in *Secret Wars* #4 (2015).

[image]

---

[**Thor** appeared as a frog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiuwTPS-Nc4) in *Ultimate Spider-Man* (2012 animated TV series) [S01E09](https://thedailybugle.fandom.com/wiki/Field_Trip) "[Field Trip](https://thedailybugle.fandom.com/wiki/Field_Trip)".

[image: Thor as a frog in Ultimate Spider-Man]

<sup>(Thanks to [Clockwork](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/103122/clockwork) for mentioning this in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276035/is-spider-man-the-only-marvel-character-that-has-been-represented-as-multiple-no/276045#comment761951_276045).)</sup>

---

**Thor** was portrayed as a cat: [**Cat Thor**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cat_Thor_(Earth-53147)) ([Earth-53147](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-53147)) in *[Unbeatable Squirrel Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unbeatable_Squirrel_Girl_Vol_1_8)* (2015).

[image: Cat Thor]

---

**Bruce Banner / Hulk** was portrayed as a dog: [**Dog Bruce Banner / Dog Hulk**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dog_Bruce_Banner_(Earth-53147)) ([Earth-53147](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-53147)) in [*Unbeatable Squirrel Girl* Vol. 2 #17](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unbeatable_Squirrel_Girl_Vol_2_17) (2017).

[image: Dog Bruce Banner / Dog Hulk]

---

A variant of **Rhino** that is a literal rhinoceros appeared in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

[image: Rhino in Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse]

---

**Norman Osborn / Green Goblin** has been portrayed as [**Norrannosaurman**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Norrannosaurman_(Earth-66)), a pteranodon and nemesis of Pter Ptarker (Spider-Rex).

[image: Norrannosaurman]

---

**Mysterio** has been portrayed as an anthropomorphized car: **[Mr. Reo Speedbuggy](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Reo_Speedbuggy_(Earth-53931))** (enemy of Peter Parkedcar / Spectacular Spider-Mobile).

[image: Mr. Reo Speedbuggy]

---

Among many other Marvel characters ([full list here](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-8311)), **Doctor Strange** has been portrayed as Croctor Strange / Steamin Strange,  **Mister Fantastic** as Mooster Fantastic, **Namor / Sub-Mariner** as Sub-Marsupial, **Iron Man** as Iron Mouse, **Steve Rogers / Captain America** as Steven Mouser / Captain Americat,  **Black Bolt** as Black Colt, **Frank Castle / Punisher** as Frank Carple / Punfisher, and **Doctor Doom** as Ducktor Doom in [Larval Earth](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-8311) ([Earth-8311](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-8311), the home universe of [Peter Porker / Spider-Ham](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Porker_(Earth-8311))).

[image: Various characters in Larval Earth]

[image: Steven Mouser / Captain Americat] [image: Black Colt]

[image: Frank Carple / Punfisher] [image: Duktor Doom]

**Mysterio**, as [**Mooseterio**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mooseterio_(Earth-8311)), also from Larval Earth / Earth-8311, appeared in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023).

[image]

---

Multiple Marvel characters ([full list here](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Earth-8101/Characters)) have been portrayed as apes and monkeys in [*Marvel Apes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Apes) (2008, Earth-8101).

**Marvel Apes Fantastic Four 2099: Doctor Strange, Jean Grey, Ghost Rider,** and **Nick Fury** (as [**Nick Furry**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nicole_Furry_(Earth-8101))).

[image: Marvel Apes Fantastic Four 2099]

The [**Ape-vengers**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ape-vengers_(Earth-8101))

[image: Ape-vengers in Marvel Apes (Earth-8101)]

**[Outcasts](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Outcasts_(Earth-8101))**

[image: Outcasts in Marvel Apes (Earth-8101)]

---

**Luke Cage, Giant-Man / Hank Pym, Wolverine, Spider-Man, Hulk, Captain America, and Black Widow** have been portrayed as werewolves in *[Marvel Zombies/Army of Darkness](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Zombies/Army_of_Darkness_Vol_1_5)* Vol. 1 #5 (2007).

[image: Werewolves in Marvel Zombies/Army of Darkness Vol. 1 #5.]

[image: Werewolf Captain America] [image: Werewolf Black Widow]]

---

Multiple Marvel characters have been portrayed as cyclopes in *Ultimate FF* #6 (2014, [Earth-61422](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-61422)).

[image: Cyclopes Marvel heroes]

---

**[Throg](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Walterson_(Earth-616))** - Though he is a different character from Thor, he is considered a Thor analogue in frog form. Throg's powers are like Thor's. Simon Walterson, who got turned into a frog (Puddlegulp), finds a sliver of Thor's hammer Mjolnir (Frogjolnir) and uses it to become Throg, the Frog of Thunder.

[image: Throg]

Throg made a cameo appearance in Season 1 of *Loki* (2021 MCU TV show).

[image: Throg in Loki]

Comment: Do all the Marvel Zombie characters count?  Most of the major characters appear in zombie form in those.  Zombies are arguably not quite human anymore...

Comment: Also in Doctor Strange Vol 2 #25 Doctor Strange met a variant of his, Doctor Stranger-Yet. He was a warthog.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Thanks. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Beta-Ray Bill is an alien version of Thor who wielded Mjolnir for a time. He’s a different person in the same universe, rather than someone from another universe.

Comment: The frog Thor made an appearance in Ultimate Spider-Man: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiuwTPS-Nc4 It's literally Thor turned into a frog

Comment: @Clockwork Thanks for mentioning that.  I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Missing: Loki as Cat on the Steve Young Thor#1 alternate cover. And almost anyone as a zombie in Marvel Zombieverse.

Comment: @Trish I can’t seem to find that cover or comic book issue. Can you link to a webpage describing that comic book issue? I found this comic book issue, [*Mighty Thor Vol.* 3 #3,](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mighty_Thor_Vol_3_3) where Loki is showing an illusion/hallucination of a "Cat Loki". Is this the comic book issue you were talking about?

Comment: @galacticninja ehhh... [*skottie Young* Thor God of Thunder # 1 (2014)](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5rA5DbefwOmuqCDxIadbfYBBoZ8-m3xriu_rZPgUC&s)

Comment: @Trish Thanks. Added that to the answer.

Comment: Oh, and Loki turns a white persian in Marvel Meow #7, #8, #9, 10 and.... need to check the other 2

Comment: yep, Cat Loki is also cast in #11 and 12.

Answer (score 15):

Definitely not the only one. Within the *[Spider-Ham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Ham)* universe alone, you have characters with different animal mutate versions:

- Mary Jane Watson

  - Mary Jane Waterbuffalo
  - Mary Crane Watsow
- Betty Brant

  - Batty Brant
  - Betty Branteater
- Namor the Submariner

  - Kay-Mar the Sub-Merchandizer
  - Sub-Marsupial
- Kraven the Hunter

  - Raven the Hunter
  - Crayfin the Bunter
- The Watcher

  - The Watchdog
  - The Whoatcher
- Ant-Man

  - Ant-Ant
  - Ant-Ham
- Captain America

  - Captain Americat / Steve Mouser
  - Ultimate Captain Hamerica
- Daredevil

  - Deerdevil / Batt Burdock
  - Deviled Ham
- The Hulk

  - Hulk-Bunny / Dr. Bruce Bunny
  - Green Ham (And Eggs)
- Iron Man

  - Iron Mouse
  - Iron Ham
- Kingpin

  - King-Pig
  - Pinhead of Crime
- Magneto

  - Magsquito
  - Nagneto
  - Hamneto
- The Fantastic Four

  - The Fantastic Fur
  - The Fantastic Ham